# Javascript: Toggle images in the same position

Tags: javascript, css

on this [website](http://guggerpark.ch/wohnen/)  I am having troubles with some toggled images.

As you can see I have a table of content on the left and with the mouse over on the single rows an image is toggled on the right.

It happens that those images are not in the same position but each image is moving "down".

How can I keep all of them on top?

This is the CSS code and the JS script I'm using:

CSS (to hide the images)

```
.haus-a-one,.haus-a-two,.haus-a-three,.haus-a-four,.haus-a-five,.haus-a-six,.haus-a-seven,.haus-a-eight {
display: none;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-2.even", function() {
$('.haus-a-one').toggle();
}); 

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-3.odd", function() {
$('.haus-a-two').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-4.even", function() {
$('.haus-a-three').toggle();
});  

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-5.odd", function() {
$('.haus-a-four').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-6.even", function() {
$('.haus-a-five').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-7.odd", function() {
$('.haus-a-six').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-8.even", function() {
$('.haus-a-seven').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-9.odd", function() {
$('.haus-a-eight').toggle();
});   

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
.so-panel {
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

causes each of your cells to have a margin and hence a height even tho the image is not visible. Remove this style from the divs that contain the images and you are good to go.

Comment: Hi, this is not what I need to accomplish. What i need to fix is the toggled Images in the same position on mouse over on the single table's rows. As you can see looks like each picture is moving down. Just the first is on top.

Comment: rephrased: every image right next to the tbale should be vertically aligned with the top of the table to the left?

Comment: Exactly this is what I would like to do :)

Comment: Then the answer is valid ;) Open dev tools and hover the divs (while image is hidden). YOu will see that each div still has a height due to the margin. If you disable the .so-panel class each div has a height of 0 (which is what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Removing

`#pg-220-0, #pg-220-1, #pl-220 .so-panel {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}`

solves your problem but you will have to check what all components it can effect.

Comment: Please explain why removing the provided code snippet solves OP's problem. While this answer might help in this specific case, nobody else could imho profit from it

Comment: @A.Hilt the images you have added is enclosed in a div which has this margin of 30px so when you are hovering on the 2nd table row and the image inside second row is toggled and the first div is having a margin of 30px which is creating a 30px gap on the top of it. You can check by inspecting your div in dev tools